# Export production database for developers

Tags: sql-server

We're developing a web application backed by SQL Server.  There will only ever be one instance, so the canonical method of creating the baseline database on a development machine is to copy down the production database.

We keep all pending database changes as SQL scripts, so at any time the developer can get a copy of production and then apply all the applicable SQL scripts.

The production database contains sensitive information that shouldn't be on development machines.  I'm looking for a good way to export the database and package it for developers in a format that's easy to import.

I've answered this question with the way I do it now, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I take a backup of the production database and restore it on another machine.  Then I run a script to delete all the sensitive data.  (I could also prune the data here if it was too large for development.)  Then I backup this database and make the file available to developers.

Backing up twice seems inefficient, but I don't want developers to have the sensitive data on their machines even temporarily.

(I trust the developers to not misuse the sensitive data, but if one of their laptops was stolen or otherwise compromised, I don't want to have to worry about the potential security breach.)